# Jquery,Bootstrap submenu is not showing in case of local .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on JQuery. Bootstrap and HTML5 in an asp.net application. I am trying to implement a simple menu in the master page. My code is like below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu
                1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is working fine when I am calling the "**jquery.min.js**" and "**bootstrap.min.js**" file directly from internet server as you can see in the code. But when I include the files from local machine like:

```
<link href="Styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js" type="text/javasript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

sub menu is not showing.
I am not sure what is actually going on.
Any help will be thankfully accepted.

Comment: try to download `jquery.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` from the `url` used earlier. then use it. and also it is better to use any one of `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.min.js`.

Comment: Any error in browser's console?

Comment: Probably the fault its the src source. If you open the console (F12) you see some error? 

PD: A image of your folder tree view may help.

Comment: Download the script files and save them in a Scripts folder in your application. Same with css. Make sure you have the files in your local machine

Comment: Can you show us the browser's console? And can you check if the files are correctly included in the head of your page?

Comment: better to use the min versions of each files

Comment: I have added all .js and .css files from from the respective sites, but result is same.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to the version of jquery, so copy this 
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js 
and put it in URL then right click save as ... you should save it as javascript file, and then add it to your project in the correct place